# Metodos de la Clase String

Tags: java, string

Tengo un Problema y es eliminar todas las vocales e inserta un `carácter "."` antes de cada consonante, reemplazar todas las consonantes en mayúsculas por las minúsculas correspondientes.
Las vocales son letras "A", "O", "Y", "E", "U", "I", y el resto son consonantes. La entrada del programa es exactamente una cadena, debe devolver la salida como una sola cadena, resultante después de que el programa procese la cadena inicial.

Ejemplo:

('tour')      =>  '.t.r'

('Codewars')  =>  '.c.d.w.r.s'

('aBAcAba')   =>  '.b.c.b'

**Este es mi codigo**:Pero solo reemplazan las vocales Help me

---

```
String palabra= "tour";


        palabra= palabra.replace('e','.').replace('i','.')
                   .replace('o','.').replace('u','.').replace('a','.');

        System.out.print(palabra);
```

Comment: Men, por gusto eliminaste tu pregunta de contar los impares desde una pirámide. Ya te iba a responder (mejor dicho, ya estaba escribiendo la respuesta) y si es que lo solucionaste, no importa, a otra persona le hubiese servido.

Comment: ajajaj Gracias el problema es que malinterprete mal el problema, es que tengo que hacer una piramide de Impares y de ahi sacar el resultado, ya hice la piramide la cosa es convertirla en Impares y despues sacar la suma de cada fila xd aun estoy craneando

Comment: si entiendo eso,pero este problema que te estoy planteando esta mejor a que si? XD

Comment: Solo llena el vector de números impares y sacas la suma. Si lo malinterpretaste, pudiste haber editado la pregunta XD

Comment: si pero de cada fila me esta matando

Comment: Mira, reactiva tu pregunta y edita lo que necesites y te respondo. Ya tengo el algoritmo.

Comment: voy a crear otro Formulario de Respuestas

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/339696/piramide-de-impares-y-sacar-el-resultado-de-cada-fila ahi esta, Gracias por el tiempo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String palabra = "tour";
       //convertir todas las letras a minusculas
       palabra = palabra.toLowerCase();

       //reemplazar todas las vocales usando una expresion regular
       palabra = palabra.replaceAll("[aeiouy]", "");

       //convertir la cadena resultante a un array de caracteres
       char[] caracteres = palabra.toCharArray();

       //crear un stringbuilder para crear la nueva cadena
       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

       //recorrer la cadena de caracteres y agregar un punto antes del caracter
       for(char c : caracteres){
           builder.append('.').append(c);
       }
       //imprimir la cadena resultante
        System.out.println(builder.toString());
```