# Piramide de Impares y sacar el resultado de Cada Fila

Tags: java, bucle-for

Aquí el problema tengo que hacer una pirámide de Impares y su fila sacar su respuesta.
Asi:

```
        Respuesta:
1         =1
3 5       =8
7 9 11    =27 Así Sucesivamente
13 15 17 19 
...
.
.
.
```

**Mi Codigo**

```
        System.out.print("Tamano de las piramides");
        tamañoPiramide=s.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < tamañoPiramide+1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <i; j++) {
                numerosImpares=i+j;
                System.out.print(numerosImpares);
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

Lo que hace en si mi Codigo es Crear una piramide de Numeros estoy craneando pero Nada Help!!

**Resultado de Mi Codigo**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta con esto:

```
System.out.print("Tamano de las piramides");
niveles=s.nextInt();

int impar = 1;
for(int i = 1; i <= niveles; i++) {
    int suma = 0;
    for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        suma += impar;
        System.out.print(impar + " ");
        impar += 2;
    }
    System.out.println(" = " + suma);
}
```